# Does Amazon Web Services (AWS) RDS support locally redundant storage (LRS) for Microsoft SQL databases?

Tags: aws

Looking at the documentation for Azure databases I see that they support LRS (local stored in three seperate location) (I'm not interested in GRS) and I was wondering if anyone knew if AWS offered the same functionality? Ideally I just want to prevent against data loss (I realise data corruption and zone availability are issues, but these are not my primary concern)

In essence, if the hardware running my database breaks, I don't loose any information?

Thanks

Gordon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon doesn't call it LRS, but the Elastic Block Store (EBS) storage [which backs RDS (see RDS FAQ, "What is the hardware configuration...")](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/) is automatically [replicated across multiple servers (see EBS product page)](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/details/#durabilityandsecurity) within the same Availability Zone (i.e. locally).

Data resilience is extremely high for RDS databases.